# problem when I use mdbootstrap dropdown in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, mdbootstrap

I have an angular project without JQuery library.  I want to use mdbootstrap dropdown for angular.
I used codes in page:
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/components/dropdowns/
I copied and paste its html code like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" mdbDropdown>
  <button mdbDropdownToggle type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" class="dropdown-toggle waves-light"
    mdbWavesEffect>
    Basic dropdown
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    <div class="divider dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the when I click in button, the menu is not shown.

Comment: Please share a snippet

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have added a proper jQuery CDN it may also caused by that if not please check this site in details https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/components/demo/

Comment: I know may be if I add jquery , this problem will be solved. But I want not to add Jquery. So if i dont add jquery , can not I solve this problem?

Comment: or just use a simple dropdown on hover with html and CSS if need check the link below https://codepen.io/sridhar-the-looper/pen/gOYPBEG